# If $z=\dfrac{(z_1+\bar{z}_2)z_1}{z_2\bar{z}_1}$ where $z_1=1+2i$ and $z_2=1-i$, then find $\arg(z)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, inverse-function

> If $z=\dfrac{(z_1+\bar{z}_2)z_1}{z_2\bar{z}_1}$ where $z_1=1+2i$ and $z_2=1-i$, then find $\arg(z)$

**My Attempt**
$$
z_1+\bar{z}_2=2+3i,\quad(z_1+\bar{z}_2)z_1=(2+3i)(1+2i)=-4+7i\\
z_2\bar{z}_1=(1-i)(1-2i)=-1-3i\\
\arg(z)=\arg(z_1+\bar{z}_2)+\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2\bar{z}_1)\\
=\Big[\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{2}+\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{1}\Big]-\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{1}\\
=\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{7}{-4}-\tan^{-1}3=\pi-\Big[\tan^{-1}\frac{7}{4}+\tan^{-1}3\Big]\\
=\tan^{-1}\frac{19}{17}
$$
**OR**
$$
z=\dfrac{(z_1+\bar{z}_2)z_1}{z_2\bar{z}_1}=\frac{-4+7i}{-1-3i}.\frac{-1+3i}{-1+3i}=\frac{-17-19i}{10}\\
\arg(z)=\tan^{-1}\frac{19}{17}
$$
My reference gives the solution $\arg(z)=-\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{19}{17}$, what am I missing here ?

Comment: Yes the argument is arctan(19/17) but not the principal value as the result is in the 3rd quadrant. So we must take away Pi to get the actual value of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the actual answer (by Peter Foreman in comment), a hint: you don't really need to multiply $z_2\bar z_1$, as $\arg \bar w = - \arg w$.